# Approaches to open-sourcing a private repository

Tags: git, heroku, web-applications

I have an application that I've built for my local fire department that I am ready to open source.

The application, once open-sourced, will be deployable to Heroku for any other fire department to use.

Typically, I would just make the repo public and blamo! Done.

However, I want keep the original repo - in some form or another - for development of experimental features and/or for some specific features that I'll add to my department but, most likely, not to the open source one. For example, I may use Twilio for SMS notifications in my department's version, but Twilio costs money to use and I would not necessarily want a feature like that in the public/open-source version.

I've toyed with using a topic branch in the public repository for (my) department-specific development or go with two separate repositories (one private, one public).

The source of my consternation, as alluded to above, is that I expect the code for my department to deviate a good bit from the publicly available app.

Has anyone dealt with something similar who can impart some advice?

Note: I realize the question is a bit subjective and, as such, if there is a better StackExchange forum on which to post this or an improved way to articulate this, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I'd simply use a branch in your local clone that you don't upload to the public repository.  Whenever there are updates that should go in the public version, you can add them to master and then merge master into your private branch.  Updates to the private branch only go there directly.  You should set the push.default configuration to some suitable value (e.g. "simple") to avoid accidentally pushing the private branch (or alternatively, set a suitable refspec for the public remote).

Comment: Thank you, @SvenMarnach! That's very helpful and is the line of thinking I was taking but just was not sure. I appreciate your time and response!